# Cannot pass parameters into a .rdlc file

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I receive an error when running the following code. It throws an error when i try to set the parameters on the report. I looked everywhere but cannot seem to find an answer what I am doing wrong here. Every example has this method to pass parameters. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Me.ReportViewer1.Clear()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Stock_Centric.OrderPrint.rdlc"
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(NewMicrosoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("dsOrderItems", dtItems.DefaultView))
    Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)        
    
    Dim paramtr(4) As ReportParameter

    paramtr(0) = New ReportParameter("Type", "Sale")
    paramtr(1) = New ReportParameter("Company", "Jabu")
    paramtr(2) = New ReportParameter("Direction", "Out")
    paramtr(3) = New ReportParameter("OrderNum", "53")
    paramtr(4) = New ReportParameter("Reference", "Kukashop 123")

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramtr)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter]'.'

Comment: Use List(Of ReportParameter)

Answer (score 0):

All your parameters are in a form of strings?

Comment: On the .rdlc page? Yes